# How to use Library Eigen on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, xcode4, objective-c++

We are developing an application for iphone 4 in xcode4 where we get an error when compiling for the device:

{standard input}: unknown: Undefined local symbol LC85
{standard input}: unknown: Undefined local symbol LC86
Command / Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

We are using the gcc 4.2 and Eigen packages such as SVD, Array, QR, LU, Core, Cholesky, etc.
However when compiling for the iPhone Simulator 4 gives no error.

As could be solved?

Comment: Did you try `#define EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE` before `#include`ing the Eigen headers?

Comment: Thanks for you help me, I can solve this problem with your answer....

Answer (score 1):

Eigen's functions are vectorized by default (uses clever properties of vectors and matrices to avoid nested for-loops and such).

the #define EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE tells Eigen ... not to vectorize.
Apple's compiler used to be gcc-4.2, which does not support vectorization. I thought the new LLVM compiler should support vectorization.